# VB.NET How to use TimeSpan to add time to another TimeSpan

Tags: vb.net, winforms, timespan

My first timespan is: `"00:01:03,160"`

and my second timespan is: `"00:00:01,100"`

i want to do an addition or subtraction between **00:01:03,160** to **00:00:01,100**

```
00:01:03,160 + 00:00:01,100 = 00:01:04,260
```

i think that the format is : hh\:mm\:ss\,fff

Comment: `"00:01:03,160"` is not a `TimeSpan`, its a `String`

Comment: There's not a single bit of VB.NET in your question. And what do you mean by _"i think the format is : hh\:mm\:ss\,fff"_, what does it have to do with your question? -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = New CultureInfo("hr-HR")

TimeSpan.Parse("00:01:03,160").Add(TimeSpan.Parse("00:00:01,100").ToString()
```

The first line is unnecessary if your current culture supports that format of TimeSpan string representation.

Comment: Value of type 'System.Globalization.CultureInfo' cannot be converted to 'String'.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the TimeSpan.Add and TimeSpan.Subtract methods, such as:

ts1.Add(ts2);

or

ts1.Subtract(ts2);

Additionally, you're dealing with strings instead of TimeSpan objects-- if you need to convert these to TimeSpan objects, you can use TimeSpan.Parse. The full syntax that the Parse method understands is here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se73z7b9.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use the `TimeSpan.Add` method:

```
ts1.Add(ts2)
```

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.add.aspx#Y684